How to remove striping from JS Datatables after applying custom styling
To remove striping on Datatables you add:
stripeClasses:[]
But I have the following styling added to change background cell color depending on the value of the cell:
        var table = $('#driverTable').DataTable({
            paging: false,
            scrollX: true,
            order: [[2, 'desc']],
            drawCallback: function (settings) {
                applyConditionalFormatting(this.api());
            },
            stripeClasses: []
        });
        $('input.toggle-vis').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
            column.visible($(this).prop('checked'));
        });
        function applyConditionalFormatting(table) {
            var higherIsBetter = {
                1: true,  // Races Count
                2: true,  // Rating
                3: false, // Start Position
            };
            for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex <= 17; colIndex++) {

                // Get all data in this column
                var data = table.column(colIndex, { search: 'applied' }).data();

                if (values.length > 0) {
                    var min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
                    var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);

                    // For each cell in this column
                    table.column(colIndex, { search: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                       
                            }
                            // Set background color
                            var color = 'hsl(' + hue + ', 100%, 75%)'; // Adjust lightness as needed



And it adds the striping overtop the custom styling I added.
How do I remove the striping?

I figured it out.
My table had a class="display" on it. This applies default styling no matter what even if I add stripeClasses:[]
After removing the class attribute it removed the stripes!

See Default styling options. The DataTables documentation is helpful.
